# unclosed quotation mark after the character string sql server

Tags: sql-server, vb6

Tengo una consulta para actualizar los datos de una tabla desde la aplicación pero me ha estado dando un error. Ya lo he hecho de esta manera y me ha funcionado, pero realmente tal vez estoy cegado.

```
m_Exec = " UPDATE CatalogoOrdenCompra SET Observaciones='" & 
         TxtObservaciones.Text & "', " _
         & " TieneDevoluciones=" & m_ContieneDevoluciones & ", 
         FechaUltimaRecepcionFormal = " & _
         "CONVERT (DATETIME ,'" & Format(FechaDelSqlServer(), "yyyy-MM-dd") & 
         "',102), IVAPorc= " & Val(TxtIVAProveedor.Text) _
         & " ,CostoDeFleteFormal=" & Format(txtCostoDeFlete.Text, "######0.00") 
         & ",CostoDelSeguroFormal =" & Format(txtSeguro.Text, "######0.00") & 
         ",OtrosCostosFormal=" & Format(txtOtrosCostos.Text, "######0.00") & 
         ",SeguimientoDespuesDeCerrado = " & auxSeguimientoDespuesDeCerrado & 
         ",UsuarioModifico='" & strUsuario & "'," & _
         " IdFactura = '" & txtFactura.Text & "', FechaFactura = "" CONVERT 
         (DATETIME ,'" & Format(dtpFactura, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss") & "',102)"
```

Es la consulta que he hecho, y este es el error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tienes dos comillas **" "** antes del 2º CONVERT:

```
... FechaFactura = "" CONVERT (DATETIME ...
```

elimínalas:

```
... FechaFactura = CONVERT (DATETIME ...
```